# Make sure a Custom Tab / In-App browser is opened inside app

Tags: android, flutter, inappbrowser, chrome-custom-tabs, flutter-inappwebview

I'm implementing a web-based payment flow which uses the chrome custom tabs implementation of the Flutter package `flutter_inappwebview`.

I also tried `flutter_custom_tabs` and `url_launcher`. No matter what I try, the custom tab on Android opens in a new window. So when I check my "recent apps" I see that it's not part of my own app.

When I now go into an asynchronous payment flow the system sometimes kills my app while being in the browser as it is in the background and the `app link` into my app leads to the home page but not into the payment screen any more.

Is there a way to ensure that the browser opens inside my app to prevent the app from being killed?

Comment: Based on my reading of: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs and specifically `Custom Tabs are a collection of configurable option requests that are sent to the end user's preferred browser.` from  https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/browser-support it seems to be a separate process.